# 'System.Web.UI.Page' does not contain a definition for 'DataItem'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telerik, radcombobox

```
<span class="telerik_bx">
    <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" 
                         ID="LowCategoryCombobox" 
                         EmptyMessage="---선택---" 
                         DataSourceID="LowCategory"  
                         DataTextField="CategoryName"
                         SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LowCategoryIdx") %>' 
                         DataValueField="LowCategoryIdx" 
                         Skin="Windows7"  >
    </telerik:RadComboBox>
</span>
```

> System.Web.UI.Page' does not contain a definition for 'DataItem' and no extension method 'DataItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Page' could be found

There is a red line at `DataItem`

What is the problem?

Comment: Rhe issue is not with Telerik component itself but with your page and the way you are binding the SelectedValue of the Telerik RadioComboBox,

show your full page markup and code to get more specific help or a valid answer

Comment: What you are trying to do by `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LowCategoryIdx")`